# Mesh disappearing when symmetrize it

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

everyone, I'm a beginner in Blender and 3d modeling, I was following a tutorial where I had to symmetrize the mesh. when I change the direction to +X to -X my mesh disappears but when i try out other directions they work, except for the one i mentioned. I would appreciate your help because i am stuck right now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Symmetrize* will use the object origin as the center of the symmetry, if the origin is shifted from the object center, here is what it will give:

[image]

So make sure that the origin is at the right position (you can right click in *Object* mode > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*). Also make sure that the local orientation is the one you want as the symmetry will take the local orientation into account, not the global one.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked when i set the origin to geometry. it turns out the origin was not at the right position.